# How to compile C file with GCC for GLIB C_2.34?

Tags: c, gcc

I was going try hack me lab but came across this error.

```
./path: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib c.so.6: version `GLIB C_2.34' not found (required by ./path)
```

I was trying to download an older version of GCC for both are equal BC I compiler file on my machine then with HTTP server I download on SSH.

I have tried different methods. I am new in cyber security.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the question should be a little bit different, as you error is

```
./path: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib c.so.6: version `GLIB C_2.34' not found (required by ./path)
```

This means that target system is older and doesn't have installed `GLIB C_2.34`, if you know what your target system is it's easier (for example by calling `cat /etc/os-release` or `uname -a`(**Note**: this one can give correct but inaccurate value for example when I'm inside docker Ubuntu image in WSL it tells me WSL instead of Ubuntu, it gives value from Kernel not file system, as in Docker Linux Kernel is from Docker Host)

So question is: `How to compile C file for older GLIBC?` (because `GLIB C_2.34` is not available in the target system)

In this case you want some older version of GLIBC, output from `cat /etc/os-release` may looks like

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

We get here that we have some older version, so to solve it we can take advantage of `docker`, it allows you to use many different version of system and applications, in this case we can use image `ubuntu:16.04` (images you can find in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com))

We can start it by using (`:rw` is important here, without this new file may be not available after we exit container)

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/work:rw -w /work ubuntu:16.04
```

It will mount current directory at `/work` inside container(I don't want to go into details of docker command here, as it's a little be out of scope, but I encourage your to learn it, for example for [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/) as it will be most useful)

As container it's new system, we need to install gcc and compile out program, we go it by (I assume file to compile is `main.c`)

```bash
apt update && apt install -y gcc && gcc main.c
```

Then we can run it by using `./a.out`
Also as this system is older we can run this binary on the newer Ubuntu(it may not work always, but in this case newer version of GLIBC supported older one), we can test this binary on Ubuntu 20:04 or 22:04 by using

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/work:rw -w /work ubuntu:20.04 ./a.out
# and
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/work:rw -w /work ubuntu:22.04 ./a.out
```

Sometimes if we just don't know, it is good to just use older version that has higher chance to work on multiple systems at once, but of course depends on the case